# Which acceptance testing frameworks are better for backend development?

Tags: unit-testing, cucumber, acceptance-testing, robotframework

By backend I mean software systems that consume data, process files or communicate using machine interfaces (REST, SOAP, CORBA, etc...). No fancy web or UI testing is necessary. I have in mind Cucumber and Robotframework but I don't know how well suited they are in the task at hand.

Comment: you probably want to consider what programming languages you need or prefer to use as part of this.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an easy answer to this question.

Sounds like you got your domain right... because if you were trying to test UI/Web components acceptance testing frameworks make not be the right tool for the job.

You have a few options

- SpecFlow
- Cucumber
- StoryTeller
- FitNesse
- mSpec
- a few others.

I'm partial to StoryTeller & mSpec.. but each of these tools have their pros/cons.
Questions you should be asking yourself (and your team are)

- Who is going to be writing/maintaining the tests?
- Are self documenting acceptance tests provide value for your organization?
- Which technology would integrate most easily with your current build process?

Answer (score 0):

I have used Cucumber to test a batch application written in perl and plsql, an informatica transformation, and am currently using it to test a telephony ivr/queueing system.  Ruby provided the gems I needed to drive the system and it was very easy for the testers to learn the language/syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If it comes to Robot Framework I have an experience with bad support in Intellij for this. I'm using IntelliBot plugin. In many cases you will know your mistake like wrong syntax,  cannot find keyword etc. late in test runtime.
Problems with finding imported libraries, no debug, no simple refactor like rename keyword across a project.